# Installation error: Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: system-installation, mac

I get the error noted above when I try to install ubuntu on my mac. I follow the instructions:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

to create a usb stick with the dmg on the drive. I restart my computer and hold option, click on the efi, and it boots from the usb drive.

I click install ubuntu, and I get the purple loading screen with ubuntu written on it, and then all the sudden I get that error, from BusyBox, and it gives me some basic commands.

Are you able to install ubuntu on a mac? I mean, I followed all the instructions, but it doesn't work, and I don't know what else I could do. I tried redownloading it and following all the instructions again.

Maybe it just doesn't workon my architecture? I have a Mid 2010 Macbook with an i5 processor.

Also, I bought a 250 GB solid state drive that I used to replace my original hard drive.

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

EDIT: Ok, if I install 12.04, and that works, can I just upgrade to the new version of Ubuntu?
EDIT2: No, for some reason the old version of ubuntu doesn't even show up when I try to boot it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. Tried a dozen of different suggestions to get it working. I found one that actually worked for me.

When Ubuntu is first loader hit <kbd>F10</kbd>. Then choose <kbd>F6</kbd> (Other Options).

I checked `acpi=off` & `nodmraid`.

Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to go back and selected `Install Ubuntu`.

This for some reason worked for me. Try it out.

Comment: It doesn't give me those options... I'm installing from a USB so that might be why

Comment: I had to do things slightly differently for 15.04  On my Macbook Air it would boot to the bootloader screen where I edited the command line to include `acpi=off` and `nodmraid`.  This allowed me to book from the USB stick without issue.  Unfortunately, it then got stuck once I clicked `Continue` from the "Preparing to install Ubuntu" step